# Product attribute value - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, cart, product-attribute

I'm looping through the items in cart and printing some values, but I cannot get the product's attribute values.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();

foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {

    $_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

    if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
        continue;
    }

    $size = $_product->getAttributeText('size');
    $color = $_product->getAttributeText('color');
    $prod_url = $_product->getProductUrl(); // Is printing ok
}
```

Both `$size` and `$color` don't have any value.
Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you able to get `$_product` object?

Comment: I think so. Being able to get the product Url means I'm getting the $_product object, right?

Comment: Please try [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70106/get-custom-option-values-of-a-product), mat that help you

Comment: Sorry but I'm not being able to get the attributes using the code on that answer because $options outputs null

Comment: normally you will get all attribute data on model load. Check if $_product->getData('size') returns raw value. getAttributeText() may be the Problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this code. Instead of `Mage::getModel('checkout/session')` use `Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')`

```
        $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

            if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
                continue;
            }

            $size = $product->getAttributeText('size');
            $color = $product->getAttributeText('color');
            $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl(); // Is printing ok
        }
```